# How do I keep my player from going over the collider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, collision

I'm making a 2D game where the player moves left and right while dodging falling objects, I put triggers so it doesn't leave the screen but sometimes when it collides with these triggers it passes this collider. I sent an image of the colliders, the Player inspector and also a collider.

Here my Player code

```
         using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isRight;
    public float speed;
    public Transform pointR;
    public Transform pointL;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;
    private float maxSpeed;
    
    [Header("PowerUps")]
  public float force;
    
   
    

     
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
     rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
      sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
      maxSpeed = 600f;
     
      
     
     

    }
         void Update()
        {
             if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            isRight = !isRight;
         
        }
        }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        
        if(isRight)
        {
             rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, 0);
            rb.AddForce(rb.velocity,ForceMode2D.Force );
             sprite.flipX = true;
             if(rb.velocity.x >= maxSpeed)
             {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(maxSpeed, 0);
             }

      
        }

        else
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, 0 );
            rb.AddForce(rb.velocity, ForceMode2D.Force );
            
             
            sprite.flipX = false;
            
        }
    }

  
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {

        if(collider.gameObject.tag =="ColliderL")
        {
            
            isRight = !isRight;
        }
          if(collider.gameObject.tag == "ColliderR")
        {
            isRight = !isRight;
        }


        // For PowerUps
        if(collider.gameObject.tag == "SpeedUp")
        {
            StartCoroutine(Seconds());
        }
     }

     IEnumerator Seconds()
     {
        rb.AddForce(rb.velocity * force);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
        rb.AddForce(rb.velocity * -force);
     }
     
     

    

}
```

Comment: Make them colliders so it can’t pass through?

Answer (score 1):

I would ideally need to see your scene setup to further pinpoint your mistakes. But these are a few common mistakes that are made:

- Tags are case-sensitive. Also, make sure to assign them.
- Your collider on one of the object is not 2D; There is [`Collider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html), then there is [`Collider2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html).
- Your collider is not marked as trigger.

Though there are a few non-related problems with your setup:

---

`rb.velocity.collider` doesn't exist. You are looking for [`rb.velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html).

Ideally you want to set physics changes (velocity, in your case) to [`FixedUpdate()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) instead.

> If you do want to get colliders from RigidBody, use [`GetAttachedColliders`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.GetAttachedColliders.html).

---

Assuming you are setting up a border which the player can never pass through, you should use a full collider instead of a trigger. This uses [`OnCollisionEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html).

---

**`new Vector2(speed, 0* Time.deltaTime);`**

`0 * Time.deltaTime` does nothing, since you are multiplying by 0.

What you are looking for is probably `new Vector2(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);`. **But** you don't need to multiply the speed by `deltaTime` since you are not moving the ball manually via it's Transform.

`rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, 0);` should be your result.

Comment: I'm using "rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, 0);" but so I put a collider using the box collider that are the Transforms, but if the Player is too fast it goes beyond this collider